# What does "filesystem:" in a URL mean?

Tags: url, uri

Recently when I was inspect-elementing Google Docs I saw some of URLs prefized with `filesystem:`

What do `filesystem:` urls mean in html5 web browsers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an HTML5 scheme requesting a cached copy of a resource from the local persistent storage, if it is available.  A site is able to store certain resources and content locally within your browser, and refer back to it using the filesystem: URL scheme.  This is part of the broader Filesystem API, which I believe is still only supported by Chrome.  Here is some documentation on the subject: [Exploring the FileSystem APIs](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)